# Start the application installation view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

i'm trying to start an installationn view after download the lastest version of my application, but the application always crashing when ttring to start the new activity.

---

This is my Broadcast receiver

```
**private BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Downloading of the new app version complete");
            //start the installation of the latest version
            Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            installIntent.setDataAndType(downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }
    }
};**
```

This my logcat

```
Process: com.astech.android.webxbettingsystem, PID: 17476
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.astech.android.webxbettingsystem (has extras) } in com.astech.android.webxbettingsystem.ui.activity.CheckAppUpdateActivity$1@1282c32
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:932)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
               Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/my_downloads/572 typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1809)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3968)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3920)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4259)
                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4227)
                  at com.astech.android.webxbettingsystem.ui.activity.CheckAppUpdateActivity$1.onReceive(CheckAppUpdateActivity.java:55)
                  at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:922)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5737) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Someone helps me please

Comment: check if you have added `CheckAppUpdateActivity` on your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Yes i have **ChecAppUpdateActivity** in my *AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing the way you are passing in the `Uri` of the downloaded APK. Try using the `COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME` column which holds the local path of the downloaded file to make a `Uri` out of it.

You code will look something like:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);


    if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(downloadReference);
        Cursor cursor = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_MANAGER).query(query);


        if (cursor.moveToFirst()
                && cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS))
                        == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
            String filePath cursor.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));


            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Downloading of the new app version complete");
            //start the installation of the latest version
            Intent installIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            installIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + filePath), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(installIntent);
        }


        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, but **COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME** is deprecated

Comment: You can try out what Google is suggesting to use here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME, I personally never used it.

Answer (score 0):

No activity that can handle intent. Use `intent-filter` in `manifest`for your's `activity`

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data
                android:host="your-link.com"
                android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: You need to set intent-filter for activity when using ACTION_VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); **when your start a new activity, if not started from an activity,** intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" **is needed.**

You have two Intent filters; you only need one. If you register the BroadcastReceiver via **registerReceiver(),** only use the IntentFilter that is the second parameter to that API call -- do not also put an  element in the  in the manifest.

Comment: i use **registerReceiver()**

Comment: This is where i register it

````
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
        registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter);

Comment: then use the second parameter as intent filter which is in your registerReceiver

Comment: debug your app step by step and find where it is crashing

Comment: I hava debug it and it is crashing when i call **startActivity(installIntent);**
In the receiver

Comment: just try this intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  instead of installIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and let me know